# How to stick a photo to a glass?

Tags: glass, adhesive

I need to glue a printed photo to a glass, and I need the glue to be completely transparent since the photo will be watched through the glass.

I've read that 3M Super 77 would work, it states that it is "clear", but others are re-positionable and that maybe it could come in handy.

The print is a Duratrans like print, not sure about the specific material, but it is a backlit-able plastic.

Comment: Judging by your comment, it seems like you are making something large and important.  A good general strategy for figuring out a best method is to make a bunch of small, unimportant things first.  Make prototypes with different glues and gluing techniques until you find something you like.  You may even find that you can use a visible glue to enhance your piece rather than distractfrom it.

Answer (score 2):

If you take a look on how glue works, you'll notice two things:

- Glue pulls together smooth surfaces by an effect, similar to the capillary effect.
- Glue increases the surface between two objects by filling the unevenness of the objects. <s>generates a high friction and thus sticks.</s> When you try to move an object above an surface, friction depends on what percentage of surface are facing each other. Usually, while sliding one above another, you tilt one of the objects and lower friction by that. A water film prevents the objects from tilt and even if water itself is a (weak) lubricant and lowers friction, atmospheric pressure will push the objects together (while water will pull it together) which are hard to remove without breaking the film.

Both are effects which water is capable in a limited factor, too.
So before you try anything, paying money for stuff that doesn't work, ill suggest trying water at first.
Don't make the surfaces dripping wet, but you should moisten them a little.
If you have a spray, from glass cleaner for example, spray a little, not too much, water from a longer range (like 1 meter or more).
You don't want it to be wet, but moist.
Then simply attach the picture to the moist surface, it will stick very well if not too heavy.

Comment: Interesting, I've read somewhere that some people used jelly too. Anyway, wont the water evaporate with time and my print fall?.

Comment: Not if both surfaces are waterproof.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to glue, you have clear tape.  It's cheap, should stick your photo to the glass, and you can move it.

Comment: The thing is, the glass would be big. Something like 100x120 cms.

Answer (score 0):

They make all kinds of printer paper these days, even [removable window cling](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B008QZ3ZF8). Link provided as an example, I've never used nor can I recommend that particular product.